# Error Connection with ebay api by net/https

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, https, xmlhttprequest, openssl, ebay-api

I am trying to connect to Ebay api using eabayapi ruby gems. I go error below:

NoMethodError: undefined method `use_ssl' 
for #

My code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'date'
require 'time'
require 'uri'

@site = URI.parse("https://api.ebay.com")
http             = Net::HTTP.new(@site.host, @site.port)
http.use_ssl     = @site.is_a?(URI::HTTPS)
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

I thought It might have problem with net/https with ruby 1.9.3

I stuck with that problem. If any know about a good ebay api rubygems prleas guide.